# Swift iOS -SplitViewController Won't Let Me Hide StatusBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, statusbar, master-detail

I followed this tutorial to smoothly hide the statusBar [smoothly hide statusBar](http://tobiashelmri.ch/swift,/ios/2016/12/08/hiding-the-status-bar-smoothly-in-ios-10.html) and everything works fine when I use it on practice projects. I use the code in other project's that do not have SplitVC but have a tabBar and uses a navVC & tableView and everything works fine. In those I can successfully make it appear/disappear.

In my actual project I'm using a SplitViewController for iPad. I noticed when I implemented the directions from the link to my SplitViewController the statusBar wouldn't hide. I then made a new project using Apple's default MasterDetailApp to make sure I wasn't doing anything wrong but it doesn't work there either. I kept all of Apple's original code and only added in the necessary methods to make the statusBar appear/disappear

1. in `info.plist` I added the `View controller-based status bar appearance` and set it to `YES`
2. in storyboard I added a purple button to the DetailVC to trigger the statusBar disappearance. I also added in the method to make the backBar button disappear/reappear
3. I added all the methods to make the statusBar disappear/disappear to the DetailVC scene.
4. I added a tapGesture to the scene to make the statusBar and backButton reappear

[image]

[image]

I clicked the Plus button on the Master scene, a date appeared, clicked it to get to the DetailVC, pressed the purple `buttonPressed` to hide the statusBar and backButton but only the backButton gets hidden. I touch the background and the backButton reappears. The statusBar doesn't move.

I kept all the original code from Apple's project's and added mines below it:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK:-  Apple's code
    @IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

    func configureView() {
        if let detail = detailItem {
            if let label = detailDescriptionLabel {
                label.text = detail.description
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureView()

        // make backButton and statusBar reappear when scene is tapped
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showBackButtonAndStatusBar))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    var detailItem: NSDate? {
        didSet {
            configureView()
        }
    }

    //MARK:- Outside of the tapGesture in viewDidLoad everything below here is what I added

    // bool to determine wether to hide the statusBar or not
    var statusBarShouldBeHidden = false

    // api method to allow the staus bar to be hidden
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
        return statusBarShouldBeHidden
    }

    // api method to animate status bar appearance/disappearance
    override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation{
        return .slide
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // 1. hide backBar button
        navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)

        // 2. set bool to true
        statusBarShouldBeHidden = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25){
            // 3. api method to allow the statusBar to disappear
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    }

    //called when background is touched and added to tapGesture in viewDidLoad
    @objc func showBackButtonAndStatusBar(){

        // 1. set bool to false
        statusBarShouldBeHidden = false

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25){
            // 2. bring statusBar back
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }

        // 3. bring backButton back
        navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**How can I get the SplitViewVC to let me hide the statusBar?**

Comment: Interesting, but Setting app (native) can hide it so we also could.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @Jageen I actually got tired of it and just decided to keep the status bar. SplitViewController has to be the biggest headache of all headaches in my iOS time. I said to myself maybe I have to change it on the SplitViewController itself but then the problem would be it'd apply app wide to every child vc connected to the splitVC. That's when I said "ehhh forget it"

Comment: nice choice, you can write your research here let see if some one will came up with different approach ( only if you are seeking for solution else just delete this question :) )

Comment: @Jageen I might get back to it. I have so many other bugs I have to get to that's why I decided to move on. I'm sure someone else will run into this problem and not realize it's the splitVC causing the issue. Thanks for the convo 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to hide the status bar through the detail view controller.  The status bar in the user interface is controlled only by the split view controller because it is on top of the view controller hierarchy. Therefore, the easiest way to control the behavior of the status bar is to subclass UISplitViewController and then override the prefersStatusBarHidden computed property in the subclass.  Also, make sure you go to your storyboard and change the split view controller's custom class field in the Identity inspector to your subclass.

---Updated Answer---
@LanceSamaria Okay, I took your code above and tweaked some things. First of all, I only added the button action and not the tap gesture.  Also, I commented out the hiding the back button, because this is important in the UI in order to be able to go back to the master view.  Anyway, now when you click the button, the SplitViewController will hide the status bar.  If you click the button again, then the status bar will reappear.

import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

var statusBarShouldBeHidden = false

func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if let detail = self.detailItem {
        if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
            label.text = detail.description
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.configureView()
}

/* override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation{
    return .slide
} */


var detailItem: NSDate? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view.
        self.configureView()
    }
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // 1. hide backBar button
    //navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)

    // 2. set bool to true
    statusBarShouldBeHidden = !statusBarShouldBeHidden

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25){
        // 3. api method to allow the statusBar to disappear
        guard let svc = self.splitViewController as? SplitViewController else { return }
        svc.statusBarShouldBeHidden = self.statusBarShouldBeHidden
        svc.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}
```

}

Also, one more really important thing.  Below is my code for the split view controller subclass.  Note that I use the same variable name "statusBarShouldBeHidden" in both the split view controller and the detail controller.

import UIKit

class SplitViewController: UISplitViewController {

```
var statusBarShouldBeHidden = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return statusBarShouldBeHidden
}
```

}

Thank you for posting this question.  This has helped my learn a lot trying to solve this problem.  Please let me know if you still have a question about what this.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I had actually thought about what you proposed but then I realized every vc connected to the splitVC would then have the status bar removed which I didn't want. I threw in the towel after that and decided to keep the status bar. SplitVC is a headache. I have everything subclassed and connected already. I'll get back to it after I finish all these other bugs I keep running into. I'll upvote you because I think your answer is correct as long as someone wants every child vc to have the status bar removed

Comment: @LanceSamaria  Hi, I don't know if stack overflow will notify you of my  updated answer, so I'm commenting you to let you know.

Comment: I looked over your answer and you are correct about having to change it in the top view controller. I had a child vc and was the only way to hide the status bar was to hide it inside its parent vc (navVC). I'll accept your answer as the accepted answer! Thanks